# Spring WebFlow: POST from flow to MVC Controller

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-webflow

I have MVC Controller as below and mapped `/home` to that controller. To redirect to `/home` from flow i use `externalRedirect:contextRelative:/home` in `view` attribute. Is possible to pass some data to `/home` in `POST` ?

**MVC Controller**

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/home", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String index(@RequestParam String data) {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

**Flow**

```
<end-state id="home" view="externalRedirect:contextRelative:/home" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

When you are specifying `externalRedirect:` Spring Webflow is going to set a redirect code and Location header on your response which simply instructs the browser to perform a GET request for the specified location.  You can include query parameters appended to this location but not POST data.

For example:

```
<end-state id="home" view="externalRedirect:contextRelative:/home?foo=bar" />
```

Also note that you can include ${expressions} in this string that will be evaluated against the request context, according to the [XSD](http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd).

Comment: Thanks. Do You have any idea how to pass more than query parameters from flow to mvc controller ?

Comment: @marioosh You can use the session, or your persistent store (DB).  But I think you may want to step back and evaluate what you are actually doing -- webflow allows you to have data that lives between requests, giving you a stateful conversation.  If you are needing to pass some of this data to another controller then it sounds like you may just have another step that needs to be incorporated into your flow (instead of this other controller).

Comment: so there is no way to use post method (in order to hide the request params from the url) ??